# Swift RegEx International

Tags: ios, regex, swift, date

I am checking for a valid birthday in a regEx after the user has entered their birthday in a date picker.

The issue is that if the phone is in Russian, Chinese, or any other language that uses other characters, the RegEx will not work due the month.

Is there an easy way to convert the month to digits (1-12) even though the month is displayed as letters and also work in any language?

If there was such a way, easy or not, it would be a lot easier to check if the user is exactly 13 years or older instead of just using the year.

```html
func isValidBirthday(testStr4:String) -> Bool {
    println("validate birthday: \(testStr4)")

    let birthdayRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z, .]+(19[0-9][0-9]|200[0-3]|2003)"

    let birthdayTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", birthdayRegEx)
    return birthdayTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr4)

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use
 'NSDate` instead of 'String'

Comment: well picking a date from the date picker returns a string, is there a way for it to return a NSDate?

Comment: The [`date`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/date) property returns the `NSDate`

Comment: To echo the previous commenters, if it seems really hard, you're doing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a utilities class for checking Regex, using in a lot of my project

```
class Regex {

    let internalExpression: NSRegularExpression!
    let pattern: String

    init(_ pattern: String) {
        self.pattern = pattern
        var error: NSError?
        internalExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &error)
    }

    func test(input: String) -> Bool {
        if let matches = internalExpression?.matchesInString(input, options: nil, range:NSMakeRange(0, count(input))) {
            return matches.count > 0
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

For your case:

```
if Regex("^(19|20)\\d\\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$").test(DateStringValue) {
    // Code to be executed in here
}
```

Hope it help.